snowflake dynamic distinct count on a column in view
I have a table with below structure and data. I want to get the distinct count on USER_ID based on WHERE clause filter. I can achieve this with below sample queries.
WITH CTE(REPORT,INSTANCE,ROLE,LOGIN_TIME,ISACTIVE,WEB_ACCESS,USER_ID) AS (
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
        ('R1','ABC','ADMIN','2024-04-05 16:00:00','1','YES','U1'),
        ('R1','ABC','DEV','2024-04-04 16:00:00','1','NO','U2'),
        ('R1','ABC','ADMIN','2024-04-03 16:00:00','1','NO','U3'),
        ('R1','ABC','ADMIN','2024-04-07 16:00:00','1','YES','U1'),
        ('R1','ABC','ADMIN','2024-04-09 16:00:00','1','YES','U1'),
        ('R1','ABC','DEV','2024-04-06 16:00:00','1','NO','U2')
)

--SELECT * FROM CTE
--SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT USER_ID) FROM CTE WHERE WEB_ACCESS='NO'; -- Gives 2
--SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT USER_ID) FROM CTE WHERE ROLE='ADMIN';-- gives 2
--SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT USER_ID) FROM CTE WHERE ROLE='ADMIN' and WEB_ACCESS='YES';-- gives 1

But the real requirement is to create an View for end users on top of this table and generate the counts dynamically as in when the end user queries the view with their own filter criteria and the distinct user_id count should be populated in different column.
However, this can't be achieved through normal view as per SQL standards. Just wanted to know from experts if there any possible way to render the total distinct count on USER_ID while the end-user have options to fire a simple select on VIEW with WHERE clause filter.
I don't want to use any UDTF. Just need info if this can be achieved through any window function or pivot or any other mean to render the distinct count as additional field in the view where end-user queries the view?
Consider view created with following DDL on temp table with above shared data
CREATE VIEW REPORT_VIEW AS
SELECT
    REPORT,INSTANCE,ROLE,LOGIN_TIME,ISACTIVE,WEB_ACCESS,USER_ID,'Use some logic to get distinct count on USER_ID dynamically' as DISTINCT_USER_ID_COUNT
FROM MY_TABLE

When I query the view REPORT_VIEW as below, I want the DISTINCT_USER_ID_COUNT should get populated for the filtered criteria
SELECT * FROM REPORT_VIEW WHERE WEB_ACCESS='NO';--This should give DISTINCT_USER_ID_COUNT as 2

SELECT * FROM REPORT_VIEW WHERE WEB_ACCESS='YES' AND ROLE='ADMIN';--This should give DISTINCT_USER_ID_COUNT as 1


Hi - it's not clear, to me, what you are expecting the output of the select from the view to be. Do you just want the distinct count returned i.e. a single column? Do you want all the columns returned plus a column for the count, all filtered by the WHERE clause - so each row would have the same count value? Do you want all the rows in the table returned, regardless of the WHERE clause, but just the count filtered by the WHERE clause? If what you want is anything other than the single COUNT column, please update you question with some sample output for the SELECT statements you've listed

What's wrong with using a UDTF?  What you are asking for is the purpose they exist.

I'm also wondering what your end users of the view are capable of.  If they are capable of running a select against a view with added where clause filters, can they not also add the distinct count?

This is not possible from my understanding.
When you define a COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) as a column in the view as below:
CREATE or replace VIEW REPORT_VIEW AS
SELECT
    REPORT,INSTANCE,ROLE,LOGIN_TIME,ISACTIVE,WEB_ACCESS,USER_ID, 
    count(distinct user_id) over () as DISTINCT_USER_ID_COUNT
FROM test;

Whatever the function used in the view is defined against the table with whatever filter has already been defined.
In such a case, when user runs:
select * from REPORT_VIEW where  
WEB_ACCESS='YES' AND ROLE='ADMIN';

We CAN'T pushdown the filter, otherwise it will affect the original view's result and will be considered as a wrong result issue. The filter has to be applied after the window function:

I guess the user would have to add this column manually when selecting from the view:
CREATE or replace VIEW REPORT_VIEW AS
SELECT
    REPORT,INSTANCE,ROLE,LOGIN_TIME,ISACTIVE,WEB_ACCESS,USER_ID
FROM test;

select 
    *, 
    count(distinct user_id) over () as DISTINCT_USER_ID_COUNT
from REPORT_VIEW
where 
    WEB_ACCESS='YES' 
    AND ROLE='ADMIN'
;

